# how to understand the occurrences of free variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am thinking that many example only takes free variable with one occurrence, such as  $(\lambda x.x )y$ where $y$ is free.

can we say $y y $ is a $\lambda$-term and two $y$ are same free variable?
I did not see such examples so far, just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible definition (From [Lambda-Calculus and Combinators](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521898850)):

> Definition 1.11 (Free and bound variables) An occurrence of a variable
>   $x$ in a term $P$ is called:
>
> - bound if it is in the scope of a $\lambda x$ in $P$
> - bound and binding, iff it is the $x$ in $\lambda x$
> - free otherwise

Let's define the set of free variables $FV$:

- The free variables of $x$ are just $x$, that is $FV(x) = \{x\}$
- $FV(\lambda x. P) = FV(P) \setminus \{x\}$ (since $x$ is bound)
- $FV(st) = FV(s) \cup FV(t) $

And maybe you just need some examples:

- $y$ is free in $y$
- $x$ is free in $(\lambda x.x)x$ (Try to work out why)
- $y$ is free in $(yy)$.

Comment: so I am right is that a single free variable could have many occurrences, such as $yyyyy$ with a single free variable $y$. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, since $yyyyyy$ is just $((((yy)y)y)y)$. Which makes $FV(yyyyyy) = \{y\}$.